# Visual Studio 2013 - Source Not Available

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

While I am Debugging whenever I click Break All Button it opens a new tab window which says this:

**Source Not Available**
-source information is missing from the debug information for this module

It works fine Edit and continue while debugging but why does the above happen? I don't want this tab window to be displayed every time I click Break All.

Just don't say It's a Microsoft new Bug!

Does anyone have an Idea how to fix that because It's annoying.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that at the time you hit `Break` the code being executed was from some external library that you don't have the source for; most likely a call to the base language library, of which you no doubt have lots of calls to all over your application.  If you did it often enough eventually you'll happen to break at a point where no library call is executing (the specific code of your program will determine how lucky you need to be for that to happen).

Answer (score 3):

It is not a Microsoft new bug.

When you `break all` you are very likely to break on code that occur within compiled libraries in your code.  The source would not be available for this, hence the error.

Edit and continue will focus on your code, not that of supporting libraries, so the error doesn't occur.  You can see this happen by trying to step into (`F11`) a 3rd party library in your project.

EDIT: Have you tried going into the `Exceptions` menu? `CTRL + ALT + "E"` and unchecking all the `Thrown` boxes?

Comment: There are some decompilers that can get around this to an extent, however, such as .NET Reflector, although it's commercial software and somewhat expensive.

Comment: @paqogomez - Step into and "edit and continue" work but before I can edit&continue, it focuses me to Source Not Available window every time I press Break all. Can I just hide this?

Comment: what is the library that it is stepping into?  is this something you built, or an outside library?

Comment: Did you get any result yet?

Comment: @Milot25 Have you find any solution yet? I've just posted a question specifically for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25518136/is-there-a-way-to-hide-the-source-not-available-tab-when-invoking-break-all